# How to invoke Powershell script from post-deployment approvals/Post-deployment gates in Azure DevOps

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, release

I have Build pipeline and release pipeline in Azure DevOps which works fine. I want to start the website using power shell script which is in repo ,only after post-deployment approvals in release pipeline.  Do some initial Manual checks and  start the website

**Release Pipeline**

`Task 1: stop website`

`Task 2: deploy website`

`Do initial Manual checks before starting the website`

`Task 3: Start website using post-deployment approvals`

Comment: Hi Did you get a chance to check out below answer? How did it go?

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid it is impossible to invoke powershell scripts from post-deployment approvals.

However, if your website is deployed to azure resources. You can run the powershell scripts by Invoking Azure Function from post-deployment gates. You will need to create a Azure function to start the website using powershell script. See document [Create a PowerShell function in Azure using Visual Studio Code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/create-first-function-vs-code-powershell).

There is another workaround using [Manual intervention task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/manual-intervention?view=azure-devops) instead of post-deployment approvals.

You can add an [agentless job](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/phases?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic#agentless-tasks) to run Manual intervention task(Notify the users to approve) after website is deployed.

[image]

And then run the power shell script to start up your website in the next job see below:

[image]